# Sitecore form's custom field not saving in database

Tags: sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I have created a custom field "RichtextCheckbox" in Sitecore forms after following this tutorial (https://pushpaganan.home.blog/2020/02/06/adding-a-custom-rich-text-field-to-sitecore-forms/)

I have created RichtextCheckbox under /sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/RichTextCheckbox

[image: RichtextCheckbox]

/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Fields/Custom Fields/RichText Checkbox

[image: Richtextbox]

/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Basic/RichText Checkbox
[image: Richtextbox]

This is the code.

```
protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            base.InitItemProperties(item);
            RichText = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["Rich Text"]);      
        }

        protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);
            item.Fields["Rich Text"]?.SetValue(RichText, true);         
        }

 @Html.Raw(Model.RichText)
```

I have created a form and added Default form save action. While posting form data to database,the custom field is not saved in database

I have inherited Save settings template in the RichText Checkbox template and also the "Allow Save" option is checked under the form (/sitecore/Forms/Test form/page/richtextcheckbox)

But the custom field is not saving. Is there anything missing in my code?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? I think the blog post's title is a bit misleading since it is talking about a custom form element, not about a custom field. 

Custom form elements won't be saved in the database, you should implement a custom field if you want to save any data from the end-user. 

you should look into these articles: 
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/en/create-a-custom-field-type.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-rating-element-with-property-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided code, you are trying to implement a custom form **element**, which does not have any HTML input, so nothing will be saved in the database. (Nothing will be posted to the server).

If you want to save any data to the database, you should create a custom form **field**.
You can follow this article

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-rating-element.html

If you need to prefill your custom field some data, you can implement a **form value provider**
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--setting-up-a-value-provider-for-prefilling-forms.html

I think you can have a look at this extension, it might cover what you want to achieve it.
https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions

Comment: no there is a HTML and I am doing a custom field   @Html.Raw(Model.RichText)

Comment: @Html.Raw will prevent encoding special characters in the Razor engine. It wont render a HTML Input (unless you pass a raw HTML input..) 
What is the value of the Model.RichText? 
It is a simple render of the value of Model.RichText property and any element/text which is not included in an HTML input during a form submit, won't be sent to the server and won't be saved.

Please have a look at this hidden field implementation. 

https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/Views/FormBuilder/FieldTemplates/Hidden.cshtml

Comment: thanks for the explanation so if I add a html input instead of Html.Raw then will it save into the database?. I saw there is Allow Save field. Do I need to implement that in the code as well ?

Comment: I have added /sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/RichTextCheckbox/Advanced which has AllowSave and also inherited Save Settings template in the RichText Checkbox template. Do I need to add AllowSave code implementation? sorry I am confused

Comment: just for testing i have added this html input  <input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.RichText)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.RichText)" type="hidden" value="@Model.RichText" data-sc-tracking="false" data-sc-field-name="@Model.RichText"      data-sc-field-key="@Model.RichText"/>  


Also added this code in (AllowSave = MainUtil.GetBool(item.Fields["Allow Save"]?.Value, false);) in void InitItemProperties

and item.Fields["Allow Save"]?.SetValue(AllowSave ? "1" : string.Empty, true); in void UpdateItemFields

But it didn't work

Comment: I suggest following this article from scratch step by step. 
http://sitecorerun.net/index.php/2019/03/14/customizing-sitecore-forms/

Your class should look like this: 
https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/Fields/Hidden/HiddenViewModel.cs

Check the base class, and check if your class is marked with [Serializable] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, but mine was a result of duplicating an existing template.

The new item contained the wrong value for the field type in `Standard Values`, so the model being posted back was wrong.

You can double check this by checking what template the field is using under `/sitecore/Forms/form/page/field`